# Want to use multiple email addresses for one contact

Tags: email, contacts

I am updating my address book on my MacBook, and filling in all the information on the cards for each contact. My contacts have both work and home email accounts listed under their name. I'd like to ensure that both are copied when I send out a mailer to them. Is there an option that will activate all emails on their card or only the one in first position?

Comment: It would be helpful to know which email client or program you're using.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you would need to enter each of the email one at a time. For contact NAME with EMAIL1, EMAIL2 and EMAIL3, you can type NAME in the to: line and Mail will give you the options to choose which email.

For all three you will need to type NAME three times. Although on the to: line it will show NAME three times, if you click on the little arrow next to the name it will show you which email each name refers to. Good luck.